# GitHub like search regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

```
type:crash status:new "status:in progress 2" type:bug email:example@example.com
```

I want it to be matched to:

**Match #1**

```
type:crash
```

**Match #2**

```
status:new
```

**Match #3**

```
status:in progress 2
```

**Match #4**

```
type:bug
```

**Match #5**

```
email:example@example.com
```

Here is what I tried:

```
(\w+:\w+|"\w+:[\w\s]+)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't match to the double quotes nor the email parts, can you please tell me how to enhance this regex to match to the above data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about specific edge cases, but this regex should match everything in your example. I tested it on Rubular.

```
("[^"]+"|[^\s]+:[^\s]+)
```

Basically "anything in quotes" or "anything not a whitespace char one or more times followed by a colon and then followed by something not a white space char"

Comment: But it matches the double quotes, which I need them not to get matched, I just need the characters inside them like so `status:in progress 2` not `"status:in progress 2"`

Comment: I think in this case you can do two things one would be to create an inner group `("([^"]+)"|[^\s]+:[^\s]+)` , and the other in to strip quotes from each match. `match.gsub!(/"/', '')`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex. Use [`shellsplit`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellsplit) from Shellwords in the standard library. It's designed for this exact thing and covers the edge cases you'll have a very had time covering with a regex.

```
require 'shellwords'

str = 'type:crash status:new "status:in progress 2" type:bug email:example@example.com'

p str.shellsplit
# => [ "type:crash",
#      "status:new",
#      "status:in progress 2",
#      "type:bug",
#      "email:example@example.com" ]
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan, this is awesome!

Comment: I will keep the above answer as the chosen one as it mainly deals with regex and answer the OP, thanks again for this awesome lib.